# Delete cache image in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, caching, camera, delete-file

I'm currently developing app for android using Phonegap technology, for your information, my app concept as below

1. Capture image (by default Phonegap will store cache image locally: i.e the image path is (file://androidappnames/cache/21323213.jpg)
2. Retrieve the image
3. Do some work with the image.

The question is, how to delete the cache image?

Answer (score 2):

For delete purpose we can use file API like following:

```
function removeAllCache(){
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory, gotDirRemove, function(error){});
```

}

```
function gotDirRemove(entry){
var directoryReader = entry.createReader();
directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        entries[i].remove(function(file){
        },function(error){
            });
    }
},function(){});
}
```

Comment: Hi, just add removeAllCache(); also in order to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not delete the cache but prevent from using cache data.

```
var success = function(){};
var error = function(){};


navigator.camera.getPicture(success, error,
    {
        quality: 99,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit: true
    }
);
```

Set `destinationType` to `Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` instead of `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`

Read more here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0rc1/cordova_camera_camera.md.html